# An actor for websocket on play framework with multiple message type - scala

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

I've been trying to use websocket on play framework 2.5 in scala.
Now, I want to exchange multiple message types.

But, I get the following errors when a client sends a json via websocket.

Do I have to choose different way to exchange multiple message types?

missing something or is there any easier way?

```
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - {"sort":"post", "to":"receiver","message":"Test"} (of class play.api.libs.json.JsObject)
scala.MatchError: {"sort":"post", "to":"receiver","message":"Test"} (of class play.api.libs.json.JsObject)
        at controllers.MessageController$MessageActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(MessageController.scala:72)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:514)
        at controllers.MessageController$MessageActor.aroundReceive(MessageController.scala:63)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
```

models.scala

```
abstract class WSMessageIn()

// Classes for input
case class PostMessage(
  sort: String = "post",
  to: String,
  ...
  message: Option[String] = None
) extends WSMessageIn

object PostMessage {
  implicit val postMessageFormat = Json.format[PostMessage]
}

case class MessageFromIn(
  sort: String = "receive",
  from: String,
  ...
  message: Option[String] = None
) extends WSMessageIn

object MessageFromIn {
  implicit val messageFromInFormat = Json.format[MessageFromIn]
}

object WSMessageIn {
  implicit def json2object(value: JsValue): WSMessageIn = {
    (value \ "sort").as[String] match {
      case "post" => value.as[PostMessage]
      case "receive" => value.as[MessageFromIn]
    }
  }

  implicit def object2json(in: WSMessageIn): JsValue = {
    in match {
      case in: PostMessage => Json.toJson(in)
      case in: MessageFromIn => Json.toJson(in)
    }
  }
}
```

MessageController.scala

```
class MessageController @Inject() (
  silhouette: Silhouette[DefaultEnv],
  ..
  implicit val system: ActorSystem,
  implicit val materializer: Materializer)
  extends Controller {

  class MessageActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {

    override def receive = {
      case message: JsValue =>
        message match { // !!The error occurs here
          case message: PostMessage =>
            ...
          case message: MessageFromIn =>
            ...
        }
    }
  }

  object MessageActor {
    def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MessageActor(out))
  }

  implicit val messageFlowTransformer = MessageFlowTransformer.jsonMessageFlowTransformer[JsValue, JsValue]

  def socket() = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    implicit val req = Request(request, AnyContentAsEmpty)
    silhouette.SecuredRequestHandler { securedRequest =>
      Future.successful(HandlerResult(Ok, Some(securedRequest.identity)))
    }.map {
      case HandlerResult(r, Some(user)) => Right(ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MessageActor.props(out)))
      case HandlerResult(r, None) => Left(r)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is: `WebSocket.acceptOrResult[JsValue, JsValue]` you expect your websocket to receive `JsValue`.

This seems to match you code below in `MessageActor`:

```
override def receive = {
  case message: JsValue => // ...
}
```

However, you shouldn't expect the conversion from `JsValue` to `WSMessageIn` to happen without your intervention.

What you could do is simply:

```
override def receive = {
  case message: JsValue =>
    WSMessageIn.json2object(message) match {
      case message: PostMessage =>
        ...
      case message: MessageFromIn =>
        ...
    }
}
```

You were probably expecting an implicitly conversion, you can get it by giving a hint to the compiler (i.e., saying what you expect):

```
override def receive = {
  case message: JsValue =>
    (message: WSMessageIn) match {
      case message: PostMessage =>
        ...
      case message: MessageFromIn =>
        ...
    }
}
```

Note: you could turn `abstract class WSMessageIn()` into: `sealed trait WSMessageIn`